# How to use mysql to update woocommerce products images

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

i wanna update thumbnails of all products in specific categories of my shop with one image.
I know the categories id and their term_taxonomy_id but I cannot do proper update statement with subquery ...
Here is my code..

```
    UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = '5898'
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
AND
wp_postmeta.posts_id = (
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_term_relationships
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE post_type = 'product' AND taxonomy = 'product_cat'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = '130')
```

Where I make mistake ??
product category id 114 and in term_taxonomy_id 130

This part of the question works good but changes ALL products thumbanils not only from specific category

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = '5898'
    WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
```

Maybe I will ask for help not for resolving my problem in my way :)

This query gives some records

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_term_relationships
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE post_type = 'product' AND taxonomy = 'product_cat'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = '130'
```

and I want to use ID (from results of the query above) as wp_postmeta.post_id to change some values in those records in wp_postmeta in the query below

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
        SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = '5898'
        WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
```

Anyone ?? Help plis....

Comment: Hi, what version of woocommerce are you using? Im not questioning your code as such but are you aware of the changes between 2.1 & 2.2+?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.9 .... and .. subquery gives me correct results .. part of query updating ALL products thumbnails, works too .. but I don't know how I can make them work together :(